# Where to place credentials(User Name and Password) in Angular8 code securely to access secured SpringBoot Rest API

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, angular8

We developed a web application that uses Angular8 for the front-end and SpringBoot for Service APIs. We secured the SpringBoot application with Basic Authentication. So that when we need to call the API from front-end angular code we need to send the user name and password with the API headers.

So we are keeping the username and password in the environment.js file in the angular project. Those credentials are exposing in client-side code which loads into the browser.

So Anyone please help with where to place these credentials in Angular code?

Answer (score 0):

Storing credentials in code is not recommended

To answer your question, you can store it in `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` or you can use `HttpInterceptor` in which you can automaticaly add headers to your every request. For more information, read [Authenticaion using the HttpClient and HttpInterceptors](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

Recommend Using Token based authenticator - users will provide its credentials and get unique and time limited access token. you can manage token creation, checking validity, expiration.